# Ошибка: column must appear in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function postgresql. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возникла проблема с использованием GROUP BY в SQL. Использую БД PostgresSQL. В интернете нашел, что в ней надо перечислять все не агрегированные столбцы SELECT-а в GROUP BY. Но проблему в моем случае это не решает.
Надо во вложенной выборке отобрать именно user на основе условия CASE WHEN, а затем сгруппировать по этому полю и посчитать максимальное значение поля sending_time для каждой группы.
Сам текст запроса (с лишними полями в GROUP BY):

```
SELECT receiver_id_id, sender_id_id, time, text, number 
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(sending_time) as time,
    CASE
        WHEN sender_id_id = 7 THEN receiver_id_id
        WHEN receiver_id_id = 7 THEN sender_id_id END AS user
    FROM forum_message 
    WHERE (receiver_id_id = 7 OR sender_id_id = 7)
    GROUP BY user, receiver_id_id, sender_id_id) AS T 
JOIN forum_message ON T.time = forum_message.sending_time
ORDER BY T.time DESC;
```

Как я могу решить данную проблему?
P.S.
Исходная таблица:

```
 sender_id_id | receiver_id_id |         sending_time          
--------------+----------------+-------------------------------
            9 |              8 | 2020-04-06 23:56:49.755201+03
            9 |              9 | 2020-04-06 23:57:47.028162+03
            8 |              9 | 2020-04-06 23:59:42.259148+03
            8 |              7 | 2020-04-07 00:00:22.941715+03
            7 |              8 | 2020-04-09 00:06:40.965788+03
```

По запросу, указанному выше, получаю:

```
 receiver_id_id | sender_id_id |             time              
----------------+--------------+-------------------------------
              8 |            7 | 2020-04-09 00:06:40.965788+03
              7 |            8 | 2020-04-07 00:00:22.941715+03
```

Т.е. изначальный смысл условия CASE WHEN, направленного на отбор последнего сообщения из переписки пользователей, пропадает. Видны два последних сообщениях: от данного пользователя пользователю с конкретным id, и наоборот.
Т.е. хочу получить:

```
 receiver_id_id | sender_id_id |             time              
----------------+--------------+-------------------------------
              8 |            7 | 2020-04-09 00:06:40.965788+03
```

Comment: По идее в GROUP BY вместо user, ты должен написать всю простыню CASE WHEN ; Мне кажется он просто не понимает алиас as user ;

Comment: Покажите, какой результат вы получаете, а какой хотите получать. Добавьте семплы данных таблиц

Comment: Добавил примеры таблиц в текст поста.